# Hibernate many-to-many mapping + join table update not working

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

Okay, so I have a Many-to-Many relationship between Directory and File. However, the mapping table also contains a timestamp (dateFound). So I've created four model classes:

- Directory
- File
- FileDirectory
- FileDirectoryID

Directory Class:

```
...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.directory")
private Set<FileDirectory> fileDirectories;

...
```

File Class:

```
...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.file", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<FileDirectory> fileDirectories;

...
```

FileDirectory:

```
...

@AssociationOverrides({

     @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.file", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fileID")),

     @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.directory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "directoryID")) })

...

@EmbeddedId
private FileDirectoryID pk = new FileDirectoryID();

...

public void setPK(FileDirectoryID pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

public FileDirectoryID getPK() {
    return pk;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    getPK().setFile(file);
}

public void setDirectory(Directory directory) {
    getPK().setDirectory(directory);
}

...
```

FileDirectoryID:

```
...
@ManyToOne
private File file;

@ManyToOne
private Directory directory;
...
```

In a service class, I have the following:

```
public static void updateDirectory(int directoryID, String directoryName,
        String directoryBaseURL, String directorySearchURL, Set<FileDirectory> fileDirectories) {

    Directory directory = (Directory) directoryDAO.get("id", ""
            + directoryID);
    directory.setDirectoryName(directoryName);
    directory.setDirectoryBaseURL(directoryBaseURL);
    directory.setDirectorySearchURL(directorySearchURL);
    directory.getFileDirectories().addAll(fileDirectories);
    directoryDAO.updateObject(directory);
}
```

I can guarantee at that point, that all the fields have the expected values (including directory's fileDirectory mapping)

The updateObject called above has the following definition:

```
public void updateObject(DatabaseObject object) {
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(object);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (trns != null) {
            trns.rollback();
        }

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

All of the other fields update correctly, but the many-to-many relations do not update.

Sorry for the long-winded post, and thank you in advance.
Samuel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any `ManyToMany` association here.. ? 
However in your exemple, the OneToMany association `fileDirectories` in Directory entity is missing attribute `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` to propagate the persistence down the association.

Comment: Thank you, the missing cascade setting was the issue.